# Matmul with different rank

Tags: python, tensorflow, vectorization

I have 3 tensor
`X` shape `(1, c, h, w)`, assume `(1, 20, 40, 50)`
`Fx` shape `(num, w, N)`, assume `(1000, 50, 10)`
`Fy` shape `(num, N, h)`, assume `(1000, 10, 40)`

What I want to do is `Fy * (X * Fx)`  (`*` means `matmul`)
`X * Fx` shape `(num, c, h, N)`, assume `(1000, 20, 40, 10)`
`Fy * (X * Fx)` shape `(num, c, N, N)`, assume `(1000, 20, 10, 10)`

I am using `tf.tile` and `tf.expand_dims` to do it
but I think it use a lot of memory(`tile` copy data right?), and slow
try to find better way that faster and use small memory to accomplish

```
# X: (1, c, h, w)
# Fx: (num, w, N)
# Fy: (num, N, h)

X = tf.tile(X, [tf.shape(Fx)[0], 1, 1, 1])  # (num, c, h, w)
Fx_ex = tf.expand_dims(Fx, axis=1)  # (num, 1, w, N)
Fx_ex = tf.tile(Fx_ex, [1, c, 1, 1])  # (num, c, w, N)
tmp = tf.matmul(X, Fxt_ex)  # (num, c, h, N)

Fy_ex = tf.expand_dims(Fy, axis=1)  # (num, 1, N, h)
Fy_ex = tf.tile(Fy_ex, [1, c, 1, 1])  # (num, c, N, h)
res = tf.matmul(Fy_ex, tmp) # (num, c, N, N)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A case for the [mythical `einsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops/reduction#einsum), I guess:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.random.rand(1, 20, 40, 50)
>>> Fx = np.random.rand(100, 50, 10)
>>> Fy = np.random.rand(100, 10, 40)
>>> np.einsum('nMh,uchw,nwN->ncMN', Fy, X, Fx).shape
(100, 20, 10, 10)
```

It's should work almost the same in `tf` as in `numpy` (using uppercase indices isn't allowed in some `tf` versions, I saw). Although this admittedly exceeds a regex in unreadability if you've never seen the notation before.

Comment: yes, I never seen this before, a little hard to understand, tring to understand the idea

Answer (score 0):

For otherone may interested
I think the answer of @phg maybe work
But in my case `num` `h` `w` are dynamic, i.e. `None`
So `tf.einsum` in tensorflow r1.0 will raise error, since there are more than one `None` shape in one tensor

fortunately, there is a [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6824) and [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/7387)
seems can handle situation that there are more than one `None` shape
Need to build from source(master branch)
I will report the result after I re-build tensorflow

BTW, in `tf.einsum` only accept lowercase

**Report**
Yes, The newest version of tensorflow (master branch) accept dynamic shape for `tf.einsum`
and it is huge speed improvement after using `tf.einsum`, really awesome